# Getting href attributes from a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get all of specific `href` attributes in `a` tag from a page.
All the `href`s that I need from the page look like this:

```
href="/46089021"
```

Whole `a` looks like this:

```
<a class="truncate openwindow" target="_blank" href="/46089021" title="Blah Blah Blah">
```

Thanks for your help.

**I forgot to mention, those `href`s have unique numbers...each business has different 8-digit number after the slash. Doesn't matter if js or jquery**

Comment: welcome to SO! could you please provide an example of what you've attempted? Also you've used several tags. Are you looking for a JQuery or JavaScript solution? Please edit the question and let us know!

Comment: You have no idea how relieved I am that this doesn't have the `[regex]` tag on it ... though, thinking about it, if you're attempting to match anything where the href is of the form `xxxxxxx` (where x is an integer) rather than specifically `46089021`

Comment: what are you trying to get . if all are same then you dont need to look right ?

Comment: If you want to do this in PHP - have a read of DOMDocument and http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('a[href=46089021]')` if you're after that *specific* href.

Comment: What end result do you want? What "*specific href attributes*" do you want (bearing in mind that `href` is itself an attribute of the `<a>` (anchor) element)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select all `<a>` with href that starts with `/` and followed by 8 digit number, you can use `filter()`

```js
var result = $('a').filter(function(){
    return /^\/[0-9]{8}$/.test( $(this).attr('href') );
});
 
//Print the result for testing
result.each(function(){
    console.log( $(this).attr('href') );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="truncate openwindow" target="_blank" href="not-this-one" title="Blah Blah Blah">
<a class="truncate openwindow" target="_blank" href="/46089022" title="Blah Blah Blah">
<a class="truncate openwindow" target="_blank" href="/46089023" title="Blah Blah Blah">
<a class="truncate openwindow" target="_blank" href="not-this-one-too" title="Blah Blah Blah">
<a class="truncate openwindow" target="_blank" href="/46089025" title="Blah Blah Blah">
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pure JS and:

> ... each business has different 8-digit number after the slash.
>
> Doesnt matter if js/jquery

```
<script>
(function () {
    let aList = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    aList.forEach(function(a) {
        if(a.getAttribute('href').match(/^\/\d{8}$/)) {

            // ... do things ...

        }
    });
})();
</script>
```

That's a self-executing function so it'll run once the DOM has loaded (otherwise it couldn't get the tags); essentially it loops through all `<a>` tags in the document, then verifies that the `href` attribute is a `/` followed by *exactly* 8 digits.

You just need to add what you actually want to do with those anchors where I've marked `// ... do things ...`

*Note:* IIRC `nodeList.forEach` *isn't* supported in IE11 (and older) so if you need to support that you can either prototype it in or just use jQuery for your selector/loop instead.

<sub>I'm only using Regex to validate the format of the href attribute, not the HTML itself, ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y can stay right where he is!</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.links to get all the anchors, then just loop through the href, like this

```js
var arr = [], l = document.links;
      for(var i=0; i<l.length; i++) {
        var aHref=l[i].getAttribute('href');
        var reg = new RegExp(/^\/\d{8}$/);
          if (aHref.match(reg)){
           console.log(aHref);
            arr.push(aHref); 
           }
      }
```

```html
<a class="truncate openwindow1" target="_blank" href="/46089033" title="Blah Blah Blah">
<a class="truncate openwindow2" target="_blank" href="/46089044" title="Blah Blah Blah">
<a class="truncate openwindow3" target="_blank" href="/46089055" title="Blah Blah Blah">
<a class="truncate openwindow4" target="_blank" href="/460890766" title="Blah Blah Blah">
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, those hrefs have unique numbers...each business has different 6-digit number after the slash. Doesnt matter if js/jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `map()` method to build an array from the attributes and/or properties of all the elements in the DOM.

If you want the *absolute URLs*, use the `href` property:

```
var hrefs = $('a').map(function() {
  return this.href;
}).get();
```

If you want the *relative paths*, use the `href` attribute:

```
var hrefs = $('a').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('href');
}).get();
```

Comment: Why bring in an entire library to do something that JavaScript can do natively?

Comment: Because the OP tagged it in the question, so I would assume they already have it available in their logic. I would agree that using jQuery *just* for this is redundant, though.

Comment: Fair enough. Didn't see the tag at the time.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/u92q068y/3/

Basically, just query the document for all of your `anchor` tags and then obtain the `href` attributes and do what you will with them. Multiple ways to do this but this is one.

```js
const aTags = document.querySelectorAll('a');
aTags.forEach( a => console.log(a.getAttribute('href')));
```

```html
<a class="truncate openwindow" target="_blank" href="/46089021" title="Blah Blah Blah">
<a class="truncate openwindow" target="_blank" href="/46089022" title="Blah Blah Blah">
<a class="truncate openwindow" target="_blank" href="/46089023" title="Blah Blah Blah">
<a class="truncate openwindow" target="_blank" href="/46089024" title="Blah Blah Blah">
```